# What is the simplest way to get "Input" appearance in the legend?

Tags: legending, style

I wish to get the complete `"Input"` appearance of the contents of the legend on my plot: the font, its style, and syntax highlighting should be the same as in an ordinary `"Input"` cell. It should have `ShowStringCharacters -> True` as well. What is the simplest way to do this?

I've found a rather long and ugly partial solution (note how `Max` appears in the legend!):

```
legends = {"Option" -> Automatic, "Option" -> (Max[#1, #2] &), 
   "Option" -> BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}]]};
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[k, x], {k, 3}], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotLegends -> (Style[#, "Input", "Notebook", FontFamily -> "Consolas", 
      ShowSyntaxStyles -> True] & /@ legends)]
```

> [image: plot]

Is there a better way?

Here is what I get without explicit font settings:

[image: screenshot]

As one can see, the font doesn't match despite the `"Input"` style. But WHY?

Comment: you can eliminate `13` and `FontFamily -> "Consolas"` on Windows (these are the defaults for `"Input"` cells)

Comment: @kglr I'm on Windows, and without them, I get another font (I updated the question)... I'm puzzled, WHY?

Comment: re "but WHY": it looks like, when a font family is not specified in `Style[...]`, `"Arial"` (which is the font family set by `DisplayFunction` of `TemplateBox` for `LineLegend`) is used.

Comment: @kglr I have found another problem: with my solution built-in functions like `Max` and `Or` are displayed in `TraditionalForm` (updated the question).

Comment: The following seems to give reasonable results: `Style[StandardForm@#, "Input", "Notebook", ShowSyntaxStyles -> True] &`

Comment: @LukasLang It works, thank you. But is there a shorter/simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, currently the most concise way is suggested by
[Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang) in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255128/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-input-appearance-in-the-legend#comment636189_255128):

```
Style[StandardForm@#, "Input", "Notebook", ShowSyntaxStyles -> True] &
```

[image: screenshot]

I'm still looking for a better/shorter solution though.